# mxGraph export image loss css

Tags: html, css, image, export, mxgraph

my english is poor,sorry,i used mxGraph js front-end invoke java back-end servlet to export image,the graph contains html and css,the format of export is png,but the result of export lossed css，but the xml data contains css

Answer (score 1):

To add the CSS in Java if using the export XML format, the createHtmlDocument(String, String) method can be overridden and the CSS can be added as an internal stylesheet (ie in the HEAD section inside a style tag) as follows:

```
protected String createHtmlDocument(String text, String style)
{
  return "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">.myStyle {color:blue;}</style></head><div style=\"" + style + "\">" + text + "</div></html>";
}
```